# Scala - convert large or scientific numbers to Long

Tags: java, scala, long-integer, biginteger, bigdecimal

Need to be able to convert 00000924843571390729101 or 2.71000000000000000E+02 to Long
Expect 2.71000000000000000E+02 to become 271

```
funky results for this: 00000924843571390729101 became 924843571390729088
val signNumber = "00000924843571390729101"

val castnum = signNumber.toDouble.toLong.toString
```

First conversion below works for 2.71000000000000000E+02, 2nd one works for 00000924843571390729101

```
val castnum = signNumber.toDouble.toLong.toString
val castnum = signNumber.replaceAll("\\.[0-9]*$", "").toLong.toString
```

Do not want to keep any decimal places so not using java.math.BigDecimal

Input string may come in as 9028456928343.0000 in which case want 9028456928343 as the Long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The weird result in the first case is due to the fact that you are going through `toDouble`, limiting the precision due to how doubles are represented.

To reliably convert from these strings to `Long`s you can try out `BigDecimal::longValueExact` as follows:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal

new BigDecimal("00000924843571390729101").longValueExact()
// 924843571390729101: Long
new BigDecimal("9028456928343.0000").longValueExact()
// 9028456928343: Long
new BigDecimal("2.71000000000000000E+02").longValueExact()
// 271: Long
```

Since you also have strings that come with decimal digits, you have to use a form of number parsing that can recognize those, even if you don't want to keep that information.

This method will throw an `ArithmeticInformation` if you loose any information, meaning the number doesn't fit in a `Long` or it has a nonzero fractional part. If you want to be more lenient you can use `BigDecimal::longValue`

```
import java.math.BigDecimal
import scala.util.Try

​Try(new BigDecimal("9028456928343.0001").longValueExact())
// Failure(java.lang.ArithmeticException: Rounding necessary): scala.util.Try
Try(new BigDecimal("9028456928343.0001").longValue())
// Success(9028456928343): scala.util.Try
```

You can play around with this small snippet of code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/qJrQn7j3Tya1x4L6x5M0sw).

Comment: new BigDecimal("20006916941148201619.00000000").longValue()  gives wrong result (1560172867438650003). Any other option?

Comment: That value is too large to be stored in a 64-bit long, you have to use a BigDecimal/BigInteger. Or you can create your own type and back it with a byte array, but you're on your own with that.

Answer (score 1):

```
val signNumber = Try(numberCleaner(signNumber).replaceAll("\\.[0-9]*$", "").toLong.toString).getOrElse(numberCleaner(signNumber).toDouble.toLong.toString)
```